# Is there any way to use NUT SMART TAG in my developed app for android or ios?

Tags: android, ios, sdk, smart-tags

i want to use NUT SMART TAG in my application for android and ios, but i didnt found any sdk or documents about it. Is it at all possible? Or it's device manufacture private information? If it is, maybe somebody know analogue for that device with opened information for developers?

Comment: Take a look at the HTC Fetch: https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/bluetooth-smart/htc-fetch/

Comment: Have you found anything for android ?